# If statement with 2 conditions

Tags: php

On my webform, there are two kinds of address-fields a user can give. But since it's a complex webform (Drupal) it's kind of hard to achieve. Every time a user adds an extra address, the form is regenerated and there will be a new item added to the `$address_afl` and `$address_bev`-array. Is it possible to compress this code so the foreach-loop starts looping with the highest value (either `$address_afl` or`$address_bev` )

```
$address_afl = $form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'];
$i = 0;
foreach($address_afl as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $test = array_keys($value);
    if(is_array($test)) {
        foreach ($test as $z) {
            if (strpos($z, '#') === 0) continue;
            if (isset($form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'][$i][$z])) {
                $form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'][$i][$z]['#prefix'] = "<div class='address-publicatie-$z'>";
                $form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'][$i][$z]['#suffix'] = "</div>";
            }
        }
    }
    }
    $i++;
}

$address_bev = $form['field_bevoegde_adressen']['und'];
$i = 0;
foreach($address_bev as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $test = array_keys($value);
    if(is_array($test)) {
        foreach ($test as $z) {
            if (strpos($z, '#') === 0) continue;
            if (isset($form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'][$i][$z])) {
                $form['field_bevoegde_adressen']['und'][$i][$z]['#prefix'] = "<div class='address-publicatie-$z'>";
                $form['field_bevoegde_adressen']['und'][$i][$z]['#suffix'] = "</div>";
            }
        }
    }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you merge your two $address_ arrays into a single array?  Maybe generalize this code into a function that takes the form name as a parameter, this way your loop is programed once and called twice.

Comment: Your indentation is confusing, Your second `if` is should not be at the same level as the first.  However, array_keys always returns an array so you don't need the second `if` and they should be deleted.

Comment: @Paul, I needed to check if they variable is an array for avoiding some NOTICE-messages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite exactly understand the logic, but you could extract out at least one method which removes lots of code duplication. I've inverted some conditions (which improves code readability) and placed some comments into the code too.

```
function processValue(&$form, $value, $i, &$form_sub) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        return;
    }

    // TODO: rename test to $keys or something more meaningful
    $test = array_keys($value);
    if (!is_array($test)) {
        // TODO: is it possible? according to the documentation 
        // array_keys() always returns array 
        return;
    }
    foreach ($test as $z) {
        if (strpos($z, '#') === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!isset($form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'][$i][$z])) {
            continue;
        }
        $form_sub[$i][$z]['#prefix'] = "<div class='address-publicatie-$z'>";
        $form_sub[$i][$z]['#suffix'] = "</div>";
    }
}


$address_afl = $form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'];
$i = 0;
foreach($address_afl as $value) {
    processValue($form, $value, $i, $form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und']);
    $i++;
}

$address_bev = $form['field_bevoegde_adressen']['und'];
$i = 0;
foreach($address_bev as $value) {
    processValue($form, $value, $i, $form['field_bevoegde_adressen']);
    $i++;
}
```

---

A possible bug: both `foreach` has the following condition with the same `$form` index:

```
if (isset($form['field_afl_dienst_adressen']['und'][$i][$z])) ...
```

Maybe you want to change the second one to

```
if (isset($form['field_bevoegde_adressen']['und'][$i][$z])) ...
```

It would make possible some other refactorings (fewer parameters etc.), as *Victor T.* suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to factor all those duplicates down into 2 function calls.

I think palacsint's observation is correct that `$test` is always an array here. In fact, I'm not sure I see why you don't just use the keys in `$value` directly. It doesn't appear the keys get changed in the loop.

```
if (is_array($value)) {
    $test = array_keys($value);
if(is_array($test)) {
    foreach ($test as $z) {
```

This refactor is similar to palacsint's suggestion but taken further.

```
function name_needed(&$addr_src)
{
    $i = -1;
    foreach($addr_src as $next) 
    {
        ++$i;
        if (!is_array($next)) continue;

        foreach($next as $z => $_) 
        {
            if (strpos($z, '#') === 0 || !isset($addr_src[$i][$z])) continue;

            $addr_src[$i][$z]['#prefix'] = "<div class='address-publicatie-$z'>";
            $addr_src[$i][$z]['#suffix'] = "</div>";
        }
    }
}

name_needed($form['field_afl_adressen']['und']);
name_needed($form['field_bevoegde_adressen']['und']);
```

Comment: I've also thought of moving a little bit further, but in both `foreach` the if condition uses the *same* key. Check my update for the details.